How to check if a comparator can be used on an object of unknown type?
Say I'm implementing a sorted set in Java with a generic <T>, like a binary search tree. The set uses a Comparator<T> to order its elements. For simplicity, let's assume the comparator is always defined.
Most collections define contains(Object), where the argument is of type Object and not the collection's generic type T.
How is a method like this implemented? You can't use the comparator on the argument, because you don't know the argument's type. You can't even check if a cast is allowed.
I can only imagine two solutions, both bad:

The set has to be created with a Class<T> object so that I can check if the argument can be cast. But clearly Java's collections framework doesn't require this, so there must be a way around it.
Just do the cast and catch the ClassCastException that might result. This seems icky.


You can see it yourself in TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator.
Spoiler: it starts with
K k = (K) key;

So it will just throw ClassCastException as said in JavaDoc (thanks @yshavit).

And to be a bit more explicit: the JavaDocs for TreeSet::contains even list a throws: "ClassCastException - if the specified object cannot be compared with the elements currently in the set". In other words, they pick the second of OP's proposed solutions. (TreeMap has the same throws for containsKey)

is the exception really being thrown at that cast? How does the map know its type after Type Erasure? Why does that cast need a @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")? AFAIK the  map has no glue what type it stores, that cast is just a NOP (check byte-code); the Exception will be (eventually) thrown by the Comparator - IDEone

actually the cast is only a NOP to the virtual machine, it serves to appease the compiler

@user85421 you right. Actual exception will be thrown at int cmp = cpr.compare(k, p.key).  To be precise it may be thrown from inside that method. To be absolutely correct it may never be thrown :)

One issue is the API design. At face value the API design of TreeSet seems idiotic. Why in the blazes is it contains(Object) which leads to the question OP has asked and this inane answer of 'yeah uh it just casts' (which is, to be clear, the entirely correct answer - just, it's bizarre as an API design choice). Why is it not contains(K) instead? The answer is simple: Because a supertype, namely, j.u.Collection, demands that contains(Object) is the signature.

@rzwitserloot yes. That API was created way before introduction of generics. And even after said introduction they decide that type safety is for cowards :) and since equals have Object as parameter and there are no other way to compare thing /s it will be ok to have contains same parameter type.

TLDR: Java API is "suboptimal".

If it was contains(E) then you wouldn't be able to call contains on a collection parameterized as Collection<?> or Collection<? extends ...>. It doesn't make sense to restrict the use of that method in that way.

@Slaw "It doesn't make sense to restrict ..." is it? It is to big of a price for my liking, Java Collection API is pretty bad anyway so there is no reason to argue about one specific method signature.

In my opinion there should be no Set<? extends CharSequence>, There should be two separate interfaces: MutableSet and ImmutableSet. And all that co/contravariant nonsense should be left for ultra rare use cases.

" TLDR: Java API is "suboptimal"." - ... because it has to be compatible with legacy code.  If you take that requirement into account, maybe it is not suboptimal.  But anyway, the collections API is what it is, and attempts to redesign it are likely to be (at best) thought experiments.

@talex Fair. Though even then, I think co/contravariance would still need to exist for most cases, just at the declaration site instead of the use site. Similar to how Kotlin implements it.
